# Angularjs does not update view on async model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frameworks

I've been having a problem with trying to keep my model separate from my controller because of lack of sync between model and view. I have looked around and found that most of the time an apply would solve the issue. However, apply does not work at all for me (either when called from the root scope or the relevant scope using chrome). In this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/WnpSWPRIiRK7ROdso9aL?p=preview) I have a demo of pretty much the problem I have on my program but instead of intervals my program has asynchronous requests or  just complicated functions that seem to also be missed by angular. In the demo I have 4 variables that should be getting updated on the view. One that is being watched by the scope, another that is being updated through a callback, another that is just plain dependent on the model and one that is being updated by passing the scope itself to the service. Out of the 4 only the callback and passing the scope to the service are the ones that update the view, even when I run apply after each update (on top of the one that already runs after each execution of $interval). What I'm trying to avoid is using tons of callbacks or promises whenever my data changes due to transformations since I have many different transformations that are possible. Is there anyway to do this or are callbacks and promises the only option?

```
var test = angular.module("tpg",[]);
test.controller("myctrl", function($scope, $interval, service)
{
  $scope.$watch(service.list.name, function()
  {
    $scope.name=service.list.name;
  });

  $scope.op=service.list.op;

  $scope.call=service.list.call;

   $scope.scope=service.list.test;

  $scope.update=function()
  {
    service.getValues(function(op){$scope.op=op}, $scope);
  };
}).factory("service", function($interval, $rootScope)
{
  return {
    list:{name:"OPA", op:"TAN", call:"1", test:"scope"},
    getValues:function(callback, $scope)
    {
      var self=this;
       var interval = $interval(function()
        {
          if(self.count>2)
          {
            $interval.cancel(interval);
            self.count=0;
            self.list={name:"OPA", op:"TAN", call:"1"};
          }
          else
          {
            self.list=self.values[self.count];
            callback(self.list.op);
            $scope.scope=self.list.test;
            console.log(self.list);
            self.count++;
          }
          $rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply();
        },2000);


    },
    values: [{name:"guy", op:"ungly", call:"2", test:"scope1"}, {name:"TAL", op:"stink", call:"3", test:"scope2"}, {name:"tes", op:"test", call:"4", test:"scope3"}],
    count:0
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only a callback function to be returned from a service. $scope.$apply is not required when dealing with angular services as the service itself triggers the digest run. So I modified the code to remove the $apply and the promise and had a simple callback returned from the service which is then updating the view with the returned data.

Code:

```
$scope.update=function()
  {
    service.getValues(function(data){
      $scope.name = data.name;
      $scope.op=data.op;

    $scope.call=data.call;

   $scope.scope=data.test;
    });
  };
}).factory("service", function($interval, $rootScope)
{
  return {
    list:{name:"OPA", op:"TAN", call:"1", test:"scope"},
    getValues:function(callback){
      var self=this;
       var interval = $interval(function()
        {
          if(self.count>2)
          {
            $interval.cancel(interval);
            self.count=0;
            self.list={name:"OPA", op:"TAN", call:"1"};
          }
          else
          {
            self.list=self.values[self.count];
            console.log(self.list);
            callback(self.list);
            self.count++;
          }
        },2000);
    },
    values: [{name:"guy", op:"ungly", call:"2", test:"scope1"}, {name:"TAL", op:"stink", call:"3", test:"scope2"}, {name:"tes", op:"test", call:"4", test:"scope3"}],
    count:0
  };
});
```

[Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6KDmG97fq9y2ay3VZMS?p=preview)

Comment: Sounds like that is the way to go, I was trying to avoid using callbacks and promises (I already have a lot of them in my controller) but I don't really see good alternatives.

Comment: True, anyway it will be a performance issue in using scope.$apply when in angular scope only so callback and promises are preferred

Comment: I found that a better solution was to either use a broadcast or a watch on the model variables that are dependent on changes. This way there is no need for callbacks all over the place when you have several methods dealing with async processes. My watch example in the plunker was actually wrong and that is why it wasn't updating.

Comment: $watch will have the digest always running and hence an impact on performance. The more $watchers you have in the code, the more slower your app will be.